# Borel rank of the set of transitive well–founded relations

Tags: descriptive-set-theory, borel-sets

Could you help me with the following question?

Let TW denote the set of all transitive well-founded binary relations $R$ on the set of natural numbers. As any binary relation $R$ on natural numbers could be seen as a point of $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}}$, we could think of TW as a subset of $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}}$, endowed with its usual topology. For a countable ordinal $\alpha$ let TW$(\alpha)$ denote the set all those relations $R$ in TW that have a rank smaller than $\alpha$.

Is it true that TW$(\alpha)$ has Borel rank of at most $\alpha$?

Jech: Set theory, Lemma 25.10, says that the set of well-founded binary relations WF$(\alpha)$ with rank of at most $\alpha$ is a Borel set, but it is silent about its Borel rank.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I would look through Moschovakis' book about descriptive set theory, or even Kechris' book.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer.

Consider $\mathrm{WO}(\alpha)$, the set of *wellorderings* of rank less than $\alpha$. It is clearly the intersection of $\mathrm{TW}(\alpha)$ with a closed set. Now, by Kechris (p.189, where he quotes Stern), $\mathrm{WO}(\omega^\alpha)$ is $\boldsymbol\Sigma^0_{2\cdot\alpha}$-complete, and each  $\mathrm{WO}(\omega^\beta)$ for $\omega^\alpha<\beta<\omega^{\alpha+1}$ is not $\boldsymbol\Sigma^0_{2\cdot\alpha+1}$.

Thus, if $\alpha = \omega^\alpha$, then $\mathrm{TW}(\alpha)$ must be at least $\boldsymbol\Sigma^0_{\alpha}$, and we have a lower bound for such $\alpha$s.

I believe that the lower bound you are looking for can be obtained by reduction to $\mathrm{WF}(\alpha)$, but I have to double check this.